# NullPointerException at PendingIntent.getActivity()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alarms

I am developing an app have a reminder feature. Reminders are saved in sqlite and when device reboot reminders are created again with BootReceiver.

NullPointerException occurs in some devices.

According to crashlytics report, app was in background 100%

Here is the crashlytics log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:345)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:308)
       at test.reminder.services.AlarmReceiver.launchAlarmLandingPage(AlarmReceiver.java:231)
       at test.reminder.services.AlarmReceiver.access$000(AlarmReceiver.java:33)
       at test.reminder.services.AlarmReceiver$ScheduleAlarm.schedule(AlarmReceiver.java:279)
       at test.reminder.services.AlarmReceiver.setReminderAlarm(AlarmReceiver.java:122)
       at test.reminder.services.AlarmReceiver.setReminderAlarms(AlarmReceiver.java:127)
       at test.reminder.services.BootReceiver.lambda$onReceive$0(BootReceiver.java:23)
       at test.reminder.services.-$$Lambda$BootReceiver$MU2rWs8I8r27tAltl1VUIV_8WwI.run(-.java:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Here is the related code:

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "alarm_channel";

    private static final String BUNDLE_EXTRA = "bundle_extra";
    private static final String ALARM_KEY = "alarm_key";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Alarm alarm = intent.getBundleExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA).getParcelable(ALARM_KEY);
        if (alarm == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Alarm is null", new NullPointerException());
            return;
        }

        final int id = alarm.notificationId();

        final NotificationManager manager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        createNotificationChannel(context);

        String content = "";
        String title = "";
        if (alarm.getLabel().equals(ReminderLabelSelectionBottomSheetDialog.LABEL_BREATH_EXERCISE)) {
            content = context.getString(R.string.breath_exercise_reminder_content_message);
            title = context.getString(R.string.hello);
        } else if (alarm.getLabel().equals(ReminderLabelSelectionBottomSheetDialog.LABEL_AFFIRMATION)) {
            content = context.getString(R.string.affirmation_reminder_content_message);
            title = context.getString(R.string.hello);
        } else if (alarm.getLabel().equals(ReminderLabelSelectionBottomSheetDialog.LABEL_MEDITATION)) {
            content = context.getString(R.string.meditation_reminder_content_message);
            title = context.getString(R.string.hello);
        } else if (alarm.getLabel().equals(ReminderLabelSelectionBottomSheetDialog.LABEL_MINDFUL_PRACTICES)) {
            content = context.getString(R.string.practice_reminder_content_message);
            title = context.getString(R.string.hello);
        } else if (alarm.getLabel().equals(ReminderLabelSelectionBottomSheetDialog.LABEL_SLEEP)) {
            content = context.getString(R.string.sleep_reminder_content_message);
            title = context.getString(R.string.sleep_time);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_notification);
        builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content));
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setTicker(content);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
        builder.setContentIntent(launchAlarmLandingPage(context, alarm));
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        if (manager != null && alarm.isEnabled()) {
            manager.notify(id, builder.build());
        }

        //Reset Alarm manually
        setReminderAlarm(context, alarm);
    }

    //Convenience method for setting a notification
    public static void setReminderAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Log.d("Alarming", "set reminder");

        if (!alarm.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d("Alarming", "set reminder - alarm is not enabled");
            cancelReminderAlarm(context, alarm);
            return;
        }

        final Calendar nextAlarmTime = getTimeForNextAlarm(alarm);
        alarm.setTime(nextAlarmTime.getTimeInMillis());

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(ALARM_KEY, alarm);
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRA, bundle);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.notificationId(),
                intent,
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        ScheduleAlarm.with(context).schedule(alarm, pIntent);
    }

    public static void setReminderAlarms(Context context, List<Alarm> alarms) {
        for (Alarm alarm : alarms) {
            setReminderAlarm(context, alarm);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the actual time of the next alarm/notification based on the user-set time the
     * alarm should sound each day, the days the alarm is set to run, and the current time.
     *
     * @param alarm Alarm containing the daily time the alarm is set to run and days the alarm
     *              should run
     * @return A Calendar with the actual time of the next alarm.
     */
    private static Calendar getTimeForNextAlarm(Alarm alarm) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(alarm.getTime());

        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int startIndex = getStartIndexFromTime(calendar);

        int count = 0;
        boolean isAlarmSetForDay;

        final SparseBooleanArray daysArray = alarm.getDays();

        do {
            final int index = (startIndex + count) % 7;
            isAlarmSetForDay =
                    daysArray.valueAt(index) && (calendar.getTimeInMillis() > currentTime);
            if (!isAlarmSetForDay) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                count++;
            }
        } while (!isAlarmSetForDay && count < 7);

        return calendar;

    }

    public static void cancelReminderAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Log.d("Alarming", "cancel reminder alarm");

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.notificationId(),
                intent,
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(pIntent);
        }
    }

    private static int getStartIndexFromTime(Calendar c) {

        final int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        int startIndex = 0;
        switch (dayOfWeek) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                startIndex = 0;
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                startIndex = 1;
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                startIndex = 2;
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                startIndex = 3;
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                startIndex = 4;
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                startIndex = 5;
                break;
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                startIndex = 6;
                break;
        }

        return startIndex;

    }

    private static void createNotificationChannel(Context ctx) {
        if (SDK_INT < O) return;

        final NotificationManager mgr = ctx.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (mgr == null) return;

        final String name = ctx.getString(R.string.channel_name);
        if (mgr.getNotificationChannel(name) == null) {
            final NotificationChannel channel =
                    new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mgr.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private static PendingIntent launchAlarmLandingPage(Context ctx, Alarm alarm) {
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                ctx, alarm.notificationId(), launchIntent(ctx, alarm.getLabel()), FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
    }

    public static Intent launchIntent(Context context, String type) {
        //Normalde labela göre farklı activityler başlatmamız gerek
        // ancak biz çoğu sayfa için fragment kullandığımız için yalnızca MainActivitye yönlendiriyoruz
        final Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        return i;
    }

    private static class ScheduleAlarm {

        @NonNull
        private final Context ctx;
        @NonNull
        private final AlarmManager am;

        private ScheduleAlarm(@NonNull AlarmManager am, @NonNull Context ctx) {
            this.am = am;
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        static ScheduleAlarm with(Context context) {
            final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (am == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("AlarmManager is null");
            }
            return new ScheduleAlarm(am, context);
        }

        void schedule(Alarm alarm, PendingIntent pi) {
            if (SDK_INT > LOLLIPOP) {
                am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(alarm.getTime(), launchAlarmLandingPage(ctx, alarm)), pi);
            } else {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTime(), pi);
            }
        }

    }

}
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                final List<Alarm> alarms = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).getAlarms();
                setReminderAlarms(context, alarms);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Alarm class that I used:

```
public final class Alarm implements Parcelable {

    private Alarm(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readLong();
        time = in.readLong();
        label = in.readString();
        allDays = in.readSparseBooleanArray();
        isEnabled = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Alarm> CREATOR = new Creator<Alarm>() {
        @Override
        public Alarm createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Alarm(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Alarm[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Alarm[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeLong(id);
        parcel.writeLong(time);
        parcel.writeString(label);
        parcel.writeSparseBooleanArray(allDays);
        parcel.writeByte((byte) (isEnabled ? 1 : 0));
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @IntDef({MON, TUES, WED, THURS, FRI, SAT, SUN})
    @interface Days {
    }

    public static final int MON = 1;
    public static final int TUES = 2;
    public static final int WED = 3;
    public static final int THURS = 4;
    public static final int FRI = 5;
    public static final int SAT = 6;
    public static final int SUN = 7;

    private static final long NO_ID = -1;

    private final long id;
    private long time;
    private String label;
    private SparseBooleanArray allDays;
    private boolean isEnabled;

    public Alarm() {
        this(NO_ID);
    }

    public Alarm(long id) {
        this(id, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public Alarm(long id, long time, @Days int... days) {
        this(id, time, null, days);
    }

    public Alarm(long id, long time, String label, @Days int... days) {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
        this.label = label;
        this.allDays = buildDaysArray(days);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setDay(@Days int day, boolean isAlarmed) {
        allDays.append(day, isAlarmed);
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getDays() {
        return allDays;
    }

    public boolean getDay(@Days int day) {
        return allDays.get(day);
    }

    public void setIsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

    public int notificationId() {
        final long id = getId();
        return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alarm{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", label='" + label + '\'' +
                ", allDays=" + allDays +
                ", isEnabled=" + isEnabled +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (time ^ (time >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + label.hashCode();
        for (int i = 0; i < allDays.size(); i++) {
            result = 31 * result + (allDays.valueAt(i) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static SparseBooleanArray buildDaysArray(@Days int... days) {

        final SparseBooleanArray array = buildBaseDaysArray();

        for (@Days int day : days) {
            array.append(day, true);
        }

        return array;

    }

    private static SparseBooleanArray buildBaseDaysArray() {

        final int numDays = 7;

        final SparseBooleanArray array = new SparseBooleanArray(numDays);

        array.put(MON, false);
        array.put(TUES, false);
        array.put(WED, false);
        array.put(THURS, false);
        array.put(FRI, false);
        array.put(SAT, false);
        array.put(SUN, false);

        return array;

    }

}
```

Comment: From the official document: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int) Your service requests activity on  launchAlarmLandingPage() function but this activity starts outside of current context so you must use the Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

Comment: If you suppose to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag in launchAlarmLandingPage method android studio give an error to change this flag. Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE, Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA, Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES, Intent.FILL_IN_COMPONENT, Intent.FILL_IN_PACKAGE, Intent.FILL_IN_SOURCE_BOUNDS, Intent.FILL_IN_SELECTOR, Intent.FILL_IN_CLIP_DATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `AlarmReceiver.java:231`:

The documentation also explains it: [`PendingIntent.getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

Flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` needs to be added to the `Intent`:

```java
private static PendingIntent launchAlarmLandingPage(Context context, Alarm alarm) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
    // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    return PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        alarm.notificationId(),
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
   );
}
```

Comment: There's is no `Intent` available in that situation, maybe only while in background.

Comment: there is not a method like addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) for PendingIntent.getActivity()